# How to remove default generated canonical tag in category page?

Tags: magento2, category-listing, canonical

In `Catalog > Categories > [my category] > Design > Layout Update XML`, I put my own canonical link.

However, when I inspected the HTML, I noticed there were two canonical tags. One of them is mine, and another appears to be autogenerated.

[image]

The highlighted one is my canonical tag. The one below is the one I don't want. I want to prioritize the first link (/all-cards) over the second (/most-popular), but the autogenerated canonical tag isn't letting me do that.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check this configuration in the screenshot to disable autogenerated canonical link
[image]